# Access Docker port from host's host

Tags: proxy, docker, openstack, kubernetes

I've set up a simple "Hello world" node server on a docker container running on a Kubernetes pod running on Magnum on a virtual machine. I created the container so that its output is forwarded to a specific port on its host pod (ie `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d docker-image`), so I can access the port and see the Hello world message just fine from that pod using `curl -i localhost:49160`. However, I cannot access the port from the host VM. I've triple-checked IPs for the pod and the pod host and I am able to ping the proper IPs, but unable to access the port with the message - I get a 503 error whenever I try. How can I curl for the message from my host VM?

I am also working with a corporate proxy, and I have accounted for it wherever I can, but I'm wondering if I missed something.

If it helps at all, [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/nodejs_web_app/) is the tutorial I used to create the container.

EDIT

After doing some fiddling, I think I may not actually have a k8s pod running, I may just have this container sitting on top of a Magnum bay node (and honestly I could be wrong about this too, the Magnum documentation is not great). So, I need to be able to access bayIP:49160. However, the IP that I use to ssh into the bay does not work, nor does the IP that ifconfig on the bay gives me work.

Comment: `node server on a docker container running on a Kubernetes pod running on Magnum on a virtual machine` And we have officially reached the Quiche Singularity. I didn't think I'd see it in my lifetime. It's... it's beautiful. **begins to cry**

Comment: Alas, I think it makes me cry for much different reasons, since I'm the one having to deal with it ;)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your problem statement - how are you running the docker container? Pods use an isolated network, so unless you expose a hostport, a port opened in the pod will not be accessible on the host.

Comment: @TimSt.Clair I forwarded a port on the container to the pod, and I want to be able to access that pod from its own host, the main VM. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.